# Как сделать форму с несколькими возможными выборами на HTML (без скрипта)?

Tags: html, form

Не могу найти решение в HTML, как сделать так чтобы можно было в одной форме выбрать несколько значений (то есть: или или) черное или белое.

Вот макет формы

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
        Выберите: черное или белое
        <input type="radio" name="sum" value="100"> черное<br>
        <input type="radio" name="bum" value="100"> белое<br>
        Выберите: черное или белое
        <input type="radio" name="sum" value="200"> черное<br>
        <input type="radio" name="bum" value="200"> белое<br>
        Выберите: черное или белое
        <input type="radio" name="sum" value="400"> черное<br>
        <input type="radio" name="bum" value="400"> белое<br>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взаимоисключение инпутов с `type="radio"` определяется атрибутом `name`.

```html
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
        Выберите: черное или белое 1<br/>
        <input type="radio" id="item1_black" name="item1" value="black" checked> <label for="item1_black">черное</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="item1_white" name="item1" value="white"> <label for="item1_white">белое</label><br>
        Выберите: черное или белое 2<br/>
        <input type="radio" id="item2_black" name="item2" value="black" checked> <label for="item2_black">черное</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="item2_white" name="item2" value="white"> <label for="item2_white">белое</label><br>
        Выберите: черное или белое 3<br/>
        <input type="radio" id="item3_black" name="item3" value="black" checked> <label for="item3_black">черное</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="item3_white" name="item3" value="white"> <label for="item3_white">белое</label><br>
        <br/><br/>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
```

На сервер придет: item1=[black-or-white] item2=[black-or-white] item3=[black-or-white].

Comment: Увы это решение я знаю, но поле name в данном примере разное sum и bum

Comment: @Kenno - Так сделайте их одинаковыми.

Comment: Решил использовать label и при выводе визуальной части формы изменить внешний вид, так что при сохранном значении name... форма выглядит употребима (а радио кнопки скрыл)